# Read and convert binary file to char file using Java

Tags: java, file, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read a shortcod-file binary file that could be found [here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/REGGRAPHS/14_3_3.html).

The method i'm using to print the content of this file:

```
public void read3RegularGraphs( String pathFile ) throws IOException {

        InputStream  reader = new FileInputStream(pathFile);

        byte [] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(pathFile).toPath());
        char singleChar;
        for(byte b : fileBytes) {
            singleChar = (char) b;
            System.out.print(singleChar);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatly, I'm getting an incorrect output format, i'm getting symbols in place of chars.

How can I convert the binary content to character format.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Charset to use decoding. Char and byte are two different things

```
List<String> stringList = Files.readAllLines(new File(pathFile).toPath(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

When you convert among Char, Strings and byte arrays, declare explicitly the Charset

```
byte[] byteArray= stringTest.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
String stringTest = new String(byteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```